# E8 root lattice: why there are some offsets of -1 away from diagonal

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, roots, lie-algebras

We know the exceptional simple Lie group root lattice, for example,

- E8, we have
  $$
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
   2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -1  \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  \end{array}
  \right)
  $$

### My questions

are that why these root lattices are not as symmetric as the following cases? why there are some offsets of -1 away from diagonal in a certain pattern?

In contrast to the symmetric matrix like this:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1& 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)?
$$

Comment: recommend Lattices and Codes by W. Ebeling.

Comment: Humpreys  does Dynkin diagrams without rushing into Lie groups  https://books.google.com/books?id=ODfjmOeNLMUC

Comment: What is the question - why does E8 exist? Also, do not confuse the Cartan matrix for the root lattice - they are closely related, but the root and weight lattices are much more rich, interesting, and symmetric.

Comment: The question is how do we understand the form of the E8 lattice? Why this form is the first one, not the second one I wrote?